# Why remove group execute for mandatory file lock?

Tags: linux, permissions

According to [this source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/mandatory-locking.txt) on Linux, there is a way to force mandatory record locking on a file if the file system is mounted to accept it.
But doing this requires adding the `setgid` bit to a file, and removing the group execute permission on the file. It states:

> A file is marked as a candidate for mandatory locking by setting the
>   group-id bit in its file mode but removing the group-execute bit. This
>   is an otherwise meaningless combination...

The logic is that the `setgid` bit is meaningless without group execute permissions. But it would seem that the opposite should be true.

The `setgid` bit will not affect users who are already in the file’s group, so the `setgid` bit should be meaningful as long as the file is executable to ”other” users, or to the owner, if the owner is not a member of the file’s group.

The group execute permission is the one execute permission that should have no bearing on the utility of the `setgid` bit.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You’re right; it’s not meaningless. 
Modes such as 2001, 4001, 6001 and even 2100
are meaningful for executable files. 
They are just unlikely (especially the first three). 
Consider a hypothetical program called `grow`, owned by `scott`, group `green`. 
If the “setgid” bit is set on this program,
that means that you want any process that runs that program
to run with GID = `green`. 
The argument could be made that it’s illogical or silly
to deny permission to run the program
to users/processes that are already in the `green` group.

But I did some experimentation to support this answer,
and I discovered something that surprised me. 
Apparently somebody read the description of mandatory locking
and took it seriously. 
In my testing, modes 2001 and 2100 don’t work correctly —
the setgid bit ***isn’t honored*** if the group-execute bit isn’t set. 
I believe that this is a bug.

You say,

> … it would seem that the opposite should be true.

I don’t know what you mean by that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  First, what I meant by "the opposite should be true" is that the other and owner execute bits should be unset to make the setgid meaningless (ie. the exact opposite, because this is every execute bit _except_ the group bit.)   Members of the file's group, I had assumed, would have group priveledges regarless of the setgid bit.

Comment: You're right, I just checked, and GID isn't honored without group execute. Perhaps a "security" feature someone cooked up?